# Converting dynamic values list from XML to XSLT

Tags: xslt

IN XMl multiple dynamic values i need to display in XSLT 
XML FOrmat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <TreatySeries>
- <AnnexTitle Number="A">
  <EngAnnexNumber /> 
  <FrAnnexNumber /> 
  <Footer>Volume 150</Footer> 
  <Topofpage /> 
  </AnnexTitle>
- <AnnexEntry>
- <Footnote>
  <EngFootNote>United Nations, Treaty Series, vol. 123, I-1654.</EngFootNote> 
  <FrnFootNote>Nations Unies, Recueil des Traités, vol. 123, I-1654.</FrnFootNote> 
  </Footnote>
- <AnnexEntryHeader>
- <EngAnnexHeader>
  <TreatyNumber>1654</TreatyNumber> 
- <Participants>
  <Participant>Advisory Centre on WTO Law</Participant> 
  <Participant>Afghanistan</Participant> 
  <Participant>Agency for the Safety of Air Navigation in Africa and Madagascar</Participant> 
  <Participant>Finland</Participant> 
  </Participants>
```

IN XML multiple  i need to display those dynamic participants in XSLT.
in this format <......>
kindly in XSLT how to display dynamic multiple values in a specified format

```
No. 1654. <participant1><participant2><participant3><participant4><......>No. 1654. Centre consultatif sur
la législation de l'OMC
CONVENTION BETWEEN THE
KINGDOM OF BELGIUM, THE
GRAND DUCHY OF LUXEMBOURG
AND THE KINGDOM OF
THE NETHERLANDS RELATING
TO THE UNIFICATION OF EXCISE
DUTIES AND OF FEES FOR THE
WARRANTY OF ARTICLES OF
PRECIOUS METALS. THE HAGUE,
18 FEBRUARY 1950 [United
Nations, Treaty Series, vol. 123, I-1654.]
```

XSLT CODE:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$AnnexEntry/AnnexEntryHeader/EngAnnexHeader/Participants/Participant[1]"/> </w:t>
                                            <xsl:if test="count($AnnexEntry/AnnexEntryHeader/EngAnnexHeader/Participants/Participant) = 2">
                                                <xsl:variable name="participant2Eng" select="$AnnexEntry/AnnexEntryHeader/EngAnnexHeader/Participants/Participant[2]"/>
                                                <w:t><xsl:value-of select="concat('',$stringAndEng,' ',$participant2Eng)"/></w:t>
                                            </xsl:if>
```

but i need to display dynamic values.

Comment: Format your code: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I seriously don't understand what is written and what you are trying to do. If you don't clarify your question we can't help you. Just provide a small input .xml sample and the desired output sample along with your current output.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are trying to display all  tags within your output, try something like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Participants">
   <xsl:for-each select='Participant'>
     <xsl:value-of select='.'>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to display multiple participant values in my output like

```
<participant1><participant2><participant3>.......<participantN>
```

in XSL how to write the code